# Rails on digital ocean. Show logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed rails on digital ocean on ubuntu 16.04 as production server. Now I'm trying to run the app on browser but there's some error.

How can I check the logs?

Comment: ssh into digital ocean server using the IP and `cd` into the folder where your app is installed. you can see the logs in `log/production.log`

Comment: Ok found it thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `ssh` into the digital ocean server using the IP address and password
2. cd into the folder where your app is installed. If you do not know where it is installed, use `locate <appname>`
3. you can find the logs in `log/production.log`. If you run your app using a different environment than production, then your log file name will be `log/<environment>.log`